# If $a+b+c=0$, show that $(2a-b)^3+(2b-c)^3+(2c-a)^3=3(2a-b)(2b-c)(2c-a)$

Tags: algebra-precalculus

If $a+b+c=0$, show that $(2a-b)^3+(2b-c)^3+(2c-a)^3=3(2a-b)(2b-c)(2c-a)$

$(2a-b)^3= 8a^3-12a^2b+6ab^2-b^3$

$(2b-c)^3= 8b^3-12b^2c+6bc^2-c^3$

$(2c-a)^3= 8c^3-12c^2a+6ca^2-a^3$

$8a^3+8b^3+8c^3-12a^2b+6ab^2-12b^2c+6bc^2-12c^2a+6ca^2-a^3-b^3-c^3=3(4ab-2ac-2b^2+bc)(2c-a)$

$7a^3+7b^3+7c^3-12a^2b+6ab^2-12b^2c+6bc^2-12c^2a+6ca^2=3(8abc-4a^2b-4ac^2+2a^2c-4b^2c+2ab^2+2bc^2-abc)$

$7a^3+7b^3+7c^3-12a^2b+6ab^2-12b^2c+6bc^2-12c^2a+6ca^2=21abc-12a^2b-12ac^2+6a^2c-12b^2c+6ab^2+6bc^2$

$7a^3+7b^3+7c^3=21abc$

$a^3+b^3+c^3-3abc=(a+b+c)(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)=0(a^2+b^2+c^2-ab-bc-ac)=0$

So I have shown $(2a-b)^3+(2b-c)^3+(2c-a)^3=3(2a-b)(2b-c)(2c-a)$. My question is I utilized both the left hand side and the right hand side to come to this conclusion. However, I'm wondering if it is possible to only utilize the left hand side exclusively to show it equals $3(2a-b)(2b-c)(2c-a)$, that is to keep manipulating $7a^3+7b^3+7c^3-12a^2b+6ab^2-12b^2c+6bc^2-12c^2a+6ca^2$ until it becomes $3(2a-b)(2b-c)(2c-a)$. Thus far I haven't figured out a way to make this happen. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Hint: If you make the substitution $x=2a-b, y=2b-c, z=2c-a$, then this problem is equivalent to showing that $x^3+y^3+z^3=3xyz$ if $x+y+z=0$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Follows immediately from

$x^3+y^3+z^3-3xyz
=(x+y+z)(x^2 - x y - x z + y^2 - y z + z^2)
$.